# how to bind a a variable in a vue template when really just want string interpolation

Tags: vuejs2

Just learning Vue2 this weekend.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<a href='/arc/locations/{{location.id}}/edit'>edit here</a>
```

but getting an error saying:

```
- href="/arc/locations/{{location.id}}/edit": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
```

This is a bit confusing - I am trying to just write out a string that wont change and it seems to want to create a bound element. How woudl I just output it as a string in the url? If I can't do that, how would I just insert it into the url using Vue?

Overall, I like it but some expected gotchas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the warning states, you should use `v-bind` (of just the [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) colon `:`):

```
<a :href="'/arc/locations/' + location.id + '/edit'">edit here</a>
```

---

Alternatively, you could make a computed property to generate the url value based off of the `location.id` and bind that:

```
computed: {
  url() {
    return '/arc/locations/' + this.location.id + '/edit';
  }
}
```

```html
<a :href="url">edit here</a>
```

Comment: thx - I generally use just jQuery for front-end so and new to Vue. I'm a bit concerned about unneeded binding and performance. The app will have hundreds of items on the page. Should I try to limit binding in this case? Or should that not be a problem performance-wise. I know a bit speculative but I don't want to spend a couple of weeks and have too many bound elements make page slow to use. thx

Comment: If it's on the magnitude of hundreds you'll be alright https://jsfiddle.net/xffxmsqx/